# Why does Date.yesterday counts as Date.today also?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model and methods:

```
class UserPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price,  :purchase_date,    

  def self.today
    where(:purchase_date => Date.today)
  end

  def self.yesterday
    where(:purchase_date => Date.yesterday)
  end
```

Why on my form if I give my date_select field `:purchase_date` 1/4/2012(`yesterday` method) it also counts as today(`today` method) and if I give it 1/5/2012 (today) it is nil?

P.S. I am using Rails `3.0.10` with PostgreSQL.

---

**Update**

This is my console returns:

```
$ rails console --s
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 3.0.10)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
irb(main):001:0> Date.today
=> Wed, 04 Jan 2012
irb(main):002:0> Time.now
=> 2012-01-04 21:28:07 -0500
irb(main):003:0> Time.zone.now
=> Thu, 05 Jan 2012 02:28:18 UTC +00:00
irb(main):004:0> Date.yesterday
=> Wed, 04 Jan 2012
irb(main):005:0>
```

Now `yesterday` is screwed up, makes no sense....

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944018/rails-3-timezone-error) may help.

Comment: @holygeek Good point, I took a look in the console it it does return my issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is happening because calculations.rb is calling the "current" method of the Date class for the configured timezone (Defaults to UTC).

If you open the rails console you can see the date at which "Date.yesterday" is calculating on by doing:

```
Time.zone.today
```

This will probably show you tomorrow's date.  So Date.yesterday for what rails sees as today, is today. ;)

You can work with the Date library more directly by doing:

```
Date.today.advance(:days => -1)
```

This will give you yesterday's date like you expect whereas active_support is returning:

```
Date.current.advance(:days => -1)
```

Comment: More readable one is to use `1.day.ago`, which gives you yesterday's date like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Time` class, you'll have access to UTC (or "zulu") time zone rather than using the environment's time zone in `Date` class.

```
class UserPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price,  :purchase_date,    

  def self.today
    where(purchase_date: today_utc_date)
  end

  def self.yesterday
    where(purchase_date: today_utc_date.yesterday)
  end

  private

  def today_utc_date
    @today ||= Time.zone.today
  end
end
```

Also, if you need to process an outside date, for example `params[:purchase_date]`:

```
Time.parse(params[:purchase_date]).utc.to_date
```